# Can I apply PL/SQL beautifer rules from command line?

Tags: command-line, plsql, compilation, code-formatting, pre-compilation

Topic is self-explanatory.

My goal is to automate the process of code beautification, so a program like SQLPlus will compile code after it has been beautified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure i understood you correctly but if you want to have command-line beautifier you should check this link: http://www.wangz.net/cgi-bin/pp/gsqlparser/sqlpp/sqlformat.tpl